# ¿Es posible recorrer caracter por caracter de un string en C++?

Tags: c++

Tengo que recibir mediante protocolo mqtt una array con varios elementos, y para esto decidí enviarlos todos directamente por un string. a esta cadena le dejé una separación de un "-" para poder identificarlos que estoy cambiando de elemento, el problema viene en que no si es posible recorrer un array.

un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer:

```
Array{"Hola","-","perro","-","Cosas"}
```

Esto se transforma a string y quedaría de la siguiente forma. PD:Esta parte es de python, aqui al menos puedo manejarme.

```
"Hola-perro-Cosa"
```

Esto debería de poder separarlo en el otro lado y que quede:

```
string1 = "Hola"
string2 = "perro"
string3 = "cosa"
```

Por cierto se me olvidó explicar que esta información esta siendo enviada de python y es recibida por arduino.

Comment: no has pensado en intentar extraer los valores de indice impar? para no tener que analizar caracteres

Comment: Si recibes la cadena como un `char*`, puedes usar la función `strtok` para ir extrayendo lo que hay entre cada carácter `-`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tienes una cadena de texto y la quieres dividir puedes realizar búsquedas para localizar los separadores y, una vez localizados, proceder a trocear la cadena:

```
std::string s = "Hola-perro-Cosa";
int init = 0;
int end = 0;
while( end = s.find("-", init), end >= 0 )
{
  std::cout << s.substr(init, end - init) << '\n';
  init = end + 1;
}
std::cout << s.substr(init);
```

Claro que también se puede encapsular en una función:

```
std::string Find(std::string const& palabra, std::string const& delim, int & init)
{
  int end = palabra.find(delim, prev);
  std::string toReturn = palabra.substr(init, end - init);
  init = end;
  return toReturn;
}

std::string s = "Hola-perro-Cosa";
int init = 0;
std::string string1 = Find(s, "-", init);
std::string string2 = Find(s, "-", init);
std::string string3 = Find(s, "-", init);
```

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza un flujo (*stream*) de datos y [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

---

Puedes transformar una cadena de texto en un flujo de datos con [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
std::stringstream stream( texto );
```

Después puedes pedir "*línea*" a "*línea*" usando el guion (en lugar del retorno de carro) como separador:

```
std::string palabra;
std::stringstream stream( texto );

while(std::getline(stream, palabra, '-'))
{
    // …
    // Hacer cosas con 'palabra'.
    // …
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BCoMwDIbP61OU7aDCCjur7El2iTW4QJvW2jLY2LM7q8jw9Cd/8n@J9l4NWs/zhVib1KNsyU0xINi7@HvTbgniKC0Ql5X4iNMU@7peZsSDJPYpfs6di2gMKI8hOGUdYw8KDNiOxoRqTMRZLbzBAysP1htimM7fRhyBfkl1AZqDuz0iNynXm1UOvp5ksFwXB4wLMTd557pzrrJQRVWJ04bTLkXZtvs0l8WDi8wKGFNgeWvEd55/).